# pause() system call and receiving a SIGINT signal

Tags: linux, process, exception, signals

I'm a beginner in Linux and Process signal handling. 
Let's say we have a process A and it execute pause() function, we know that puts the current process to sleep until a signal is received by the process.
But when we type ctrl-c, kernel also sends a SIGINT to process A and when A receives the signal, it execute the SIGINT's default handler which is terminating the current process. So my question is:

Does the process A resume first or handler get executed first?

Answer (score 1):

For simplicity, let's assume process A has only a single thread, which is [blocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blocking_(computing)) in a `pause()` call, and exactly one signal gets sent to the process.

> Does the process A resume first or handler get executed first?

The signal handler gets executed first, then the `pause()` call returns.

---

- What if there are multiple signals?

  Standard signals are not queued, so if you send say two `INT` signals to the process very quickly in succession, only one of them is delivered.

  If there are multiple signals, the order is unspecified.
- What about POSIX realtime signals? (`SIGRTMIN+0` to `SIGRTMAX-0`)

  They are just like standard named signals, except they are queued (to a limit), and if more than one of them is pending, they get delivered in increasing numerical order.

  If there are both standard and realtime signals pending, it is unspecified which ones get delivered first; although in practice, in Linux and many other systems, the standard signals get delivered first, then the realtime ones.
- What if there are multiple threads in the process?

  The kernel will pick one thread among those that do not have the signal masked (via `sigprocmask()` or `pthread_sigmask()`), and use that thread to deliver the signal to the signal handler.

  If there are more than one thread blocking in a `pause()` call, one of them gets woken up.  If there are more than one pending signal, it is unspecified whether the one woken thread handles them all, or if more than one thread is woken up.

In general, I warmly recommend reading the [`man 7 signal`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html), [`man 7 signal-safety`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal-safety.7.html), [`man 2 sigaction`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html), [`man 2 sigqueue`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigqueue.2.html), and [`man 2 sigwaitinfo`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigwaitinfo.2.html) man pages. (While the links go to the Linux man pages project, each of the pages includes a Conforming To section naming the related standards, and Linux-specific behaviour is clearly marked.)